# Conditionally apply a tax zone in commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Many of the customers we'll be selling to are tax-exempt entities. We're located in OH, so for OH customers we're applying sales tax through the Tax Zone setup in Commerce. Is there a way to not apply the tax based on some conditional, even though their billing address is in OH?

Answer (score 4):

OK So I figured this one out eventually. It's a very hacky fix. I added an [adjuster](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters) that is basically an exact copy of the built-in Tax Adjuster (found at `plugins/commerce/Commerce/Adjusters/Commerce_TaxAdjuster.php`). The only difference is that I added a condition to check for my Tax Exempt field (and that we're in the OH tax zone), and then *removed* the tax amount instead of added it.

ie, I changed things like

```
$allRemovedTax += $amount;
$item->tax += $amount;
```

to

```
$allRemovedTax -= $amount;
$item->tax -= $amount;
```

And then added the whole thing to a new custom plugin.

What this results in is tax being applied normally, and then the same tax being removed.

[image]

If anybody comes across this and has a better solution, I'd love to hear it. But this works for now.

Comment: That alone did not work for me, I needed to modify optionsJson array like this: `        $taxRateAttributes = $taxRate->attributes;`
`        $taxRateAttributes["name"] .= " Excempt";`
`        $taxRateAttributes["rate"] = -$taxRateAttributes["rate"];`
`        $adjustment->optionsJson = $taxRateAttributes;`